# excel long nested if

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wrote a nested loop based on columns (A,B & C) and placed it into column D2 and dragged it down to D15 but it seems to stop working when it hits the sports section with remaining values as FALSE

```html
=IF(A2="fruit","fruit",
IF(A2="instrument","instrument",
IF(A2="colours",
    IF(B2="red","red",
    IF(B2="orange","orange",
IF(A2="sports",
    IF(B2="soccer","soccer",
    IF(B2="basketball","basketball",
IF(A2="fighting",
    IF(B2="taekwando","taekwando",
    IF(B2="boxing","boxing",
    IF(B2="blood",
        IF(C2="mma","mma",
        IF(C2="ufc","ufc",
IF(A2="planets",
    IF(B2="earth","earth",
    IF(B2="dwarf",
        IF(C2="pluto","pluto",
IF(A2="cars",
    IF(B2="ford","ford",
    IF(B2="toyota","toyota")))))))))))))))))))))
```

Not sure where I am going wrong with the nested loop but it fails when it hits the sports group and produces FALSE for the remaining values in column D

```html
   ______A_____ _____B_____ ______C_____ _____D______
  1|Product    |Category   |Sub-category|Result      |
  2|fruit      |fruit      |            |fruit       |
  3|instrument |instrument |            |instrument  |
  4|colours    |red        |            |red         |
  5|colours    |orange     |            |orange      |
  6|sports     |soccer     |            |FALSE       | <-- failure starts here
  7|sports     |basketball |            |FALSE       |
  8|fighting   |taekwando  |            |FALSE       |
  9|fighting   |boxing     |            |FALSE       |
 10|fighting   |blood      |mma         |FALSE       |
 11|fighting   |blood      |ufc         |FALSE       |
 12|planets    |earth      |            |FALSE       |
 13|planets    |pluto      |dwarf       |FALSE       |
 14|cars       |ford       |            |FALSE       |
 15|cars       |toyota     |            |FALSE       |
```

Would appreciate some help to improve the formula to return the values as indicated in the forumla

Comment: As I see it, you can use `=IF(C2<>"",C2,IF(B2<>"",B2,IF(A2<>"",A2,"No input!")))` to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i tried to reproduce the issue, I think the brackets are messed.
Please try using [`IFS`](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-ifs-function) where you need multiple nested conditions so that you can reduce the complexity of the code. Try the below snippet.

```
=IF(A7="fruit","fruit",
IF(A7="instrument","instrument",
IF(A7="colours",
IFS(B7="red","red",B7="orange","orange"),
IF(A7="sports",
IFS(B7="soccer","soccer",B7="basketball","basketball"),
IF(A7="cars",
IFS(B7="ford","ford",B7="toyota","toyota"))))))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: looks good but incomplete. Can you update it to include all the categories? it's missing "fighting" & "planets" both of which are important as they have a sub-category which i need to be able to reference also.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to get the last non-empty (sub) category :

```
 =IF(C2 > "", C2, B2)
```

Answer (score 0):

using formula given by @Ashwin (thank you!) i improved it to include all categories. This seems to be working as expected.

```html
=IF(A2="fruit","fruit",
IF(A2="instrument","instrument",
IF(A2="colours",
IFS(B2="red","red",B2="orange","orange"),
IF(A2="sports",
IFS(B2="soccer","soccer",B2="basketball","basketball"),
IF(A2="fighting",
IFS(B2="taekwando","taekwando",B2="boxing","boxing",B2="blood",IF(C2="mma","mma",IF(C2="ufc","ufc","not met"))),
IF(A2="planets",
IFS(B2="earth","earth",B2="dwarf",IF(C2="pluto","pluto","not met")),
IF(A2="cars",
IFS(B2="ford","ford",B2="toyota","toyota"))))))))
```

Comment: Its Ash`w`in :), Glad i could help.